# Symfony2 security.yml: http basic auth is returning 500 instead of 401

Tags: symfony, basic-authentication

I'm trying to set-up a very simple http-basic authentication with symfony 2. Unfortunatley I keep getting an 500 HTTP error code `AccessDeniedException: Access Denied`, instead of 401, which would force the browser to show the username/password box.

This is my security.yml:

```
jms_security_extra:
    secure_all_services: false
    expressions: true

security:
    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous: ~
            http_basic:
                realm: "Flow"

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/flow/checkout/, roles: ROLE_USER }

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    user:  { password: userpass, roles: ROLE_USER }
                    admin: { password: kitten, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }

    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

This is the URL I'm calling: `http://local.shop/web/app_dev.php/flow/checkout`

And this is the answer I'm getting:
[image]

Comment: shouldn't you have form_login: { check_path: ..., login_path: ... } under secured_area tab?

Comment: No. I'm using http-basic authentication. This his handled by the browser once it get's a 403 response.

Comment: ok, not very familiar with that concept, but you could check the full security configuration reference: http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/reference/configuration/security.html I see that there the key `realm` is used under `http_digest` key. See last chapter HTTP-Digest Authentication if it helps

Comment: As stated in the title this is about http basic authentication. http digest authentication is a different thing.

Comment: I'm having this problem too now. I think the framework should return 403 by default, but is converting the exception to a 500, like with every exception that isn't caught.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with `pattern: .*` ?

```
security:
    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            pattern: .*
            anonymous: ~
            http_basic:
                realm: "Flow"
```

I suppose that your firewall is bypassed and you try to access directly to a "section" of your application, that you're not able to access if you're not authenticated

With your "old" path, you ask the firewall to "take request into account" only if that request is to `/` url (that means /foo or /foo/bar or /foo/bar/foobar aren't intercepted)

### UPDATE

```
[2013-03-18 09:20:48] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2013-03-18 09:20:48] security.INFO: Populated SecurityContext with an anonymous Token [] []
[2013-03-18 09:20:48] security.INFO: No expression found; abstaining from voting. [] []
[2013-03-18 09:20:48] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.exception" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ExceptionListener::onKernelException". [] []
[2013-03-18 09:20:48] security.DEBUG: Access is denied (user is not fully authenticated) by "/var/www/html/cm/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/AccessListener.php" at line 73; redirecting to authentication entry point [] []
[2013-03-18 09:20:48] security.DEBUG: Calling Authentication entry point [] []
```

This is an example of log, when kernel intercept a request for a "must-have-auth" resource

Comment: Changing the pattern doesn't help. Nothing changes (cache cleared ;-) ).

Comment: @BetaRide: what's the url you're requesting for?

Comment: @BetaRide: are you sure that my solution isn't suitable? I'm sure that `/` will not intercept your call and, so, you're anonymous to the browser

Comment: I debugged the FireWall component and can confirm that `/` will ineed intercept every call to your site starting with `/`.

Comment: @BetaRide: from your screenshot, doesn't seem that request is intercepted by firewall. See my update